# Open source Android music player that supports Opus codec/files

Tags: android, open-source, music

Opus is a rather new codec that has [better performance](http://opus-codec.org/comparison/) in terms of quality per bitrate than MP3 or Vorbis and [it's open and royalty-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_(audio_format)).

Android can play it since Android 5, but my native CyanogenMod CM12.1 Music player doesn't recognize the .opus files. Even if I rename them as .ogg they are skipped and it won't list them. If I force the music player to play them, it does play but in a kind of simple popup screen.

Is there a music player for Android that is open source and can play and list Opus files?

Comment: Try [GoneMAD player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gonemad.gmmp)

Comment: Thx, but, as a Android AOSP user I don't use Google play/market. Can't find it in F-Droid.

Comment: You could try Vanilla Music, it is open source, and available on F-Droid. Though this issue says there's problems playing Opus files on Android 5. https://github.com/vanilla-music/vanilla/issues/123

Comment: I tried it. Vanilla Music does indeed play opus files, but it won't list them, nor will it show any meta info while playing (title etc). The only way to play is  with the files-tab.

Answer (score 2):

## [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-android.html)

It does list albums/maps of opus files with no problem.

And it is in the [F-Droid repository](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=vlc&fdid=org.videolan.vlc), so available for Android Open Source Project (AOSP) users.

Comment: it plays opus, but doesn't have a Shuffle option, it's amazing, we're back to the stone age with Android...